# Move cursor to start of line with keyboard shortcut in sublime

Tags: sublimetext

When your cursor is at the start of a line how do you jump to the first character.

Each time I try (with ctrl + -> ) it jumps past the first word eg:

```
"          DB::dosomecoolstuff();"
```

The cursor here jumps to the end of the "B" which is really annoying.

I had a look at the ref: http://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html

No joy as far as i could see

Comment: ctrl+arrow doesn't work?

Comment: sorry i should have said how i was trying :) and this is it.. ctrl + -> jumps passed the first word

Comment: ctrl + -> and ctrl + <-?

Comment: Yes, but this is what I am doing. In every other editor i can just do "ctrl + ->" and jumps to the start of the first character in the line. Sublime is a two step process, "ctrl + ->" then followed by "ctrl + <-"  I just wondered if there was some setting somewhere that could turn this into a normal one step process

Answer (score 5):

If you're at the beginning of a line (or actually anywhere in a line), you can press <kbd>Home</kbd> and the cursor will move to just before the first non-whitespace character on the line. Press <kbd>Home</kbd> again, and it will move to the very beginning of the line (column 1).

Comment: Kind of solution