# How can I go to the start of overflowing lines wrap in sublime text when word wrap is on?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm editing a text in sublime text. Word wrap is on, and a few lines are overflowing in the middle of my text.

I'd like to put the cursor at the *actual* start of each line (and not the overflowing start) in order to add one symbol. So I select all of the lines, but if I hit the *split into lines* command (ctrl+shift+L) and then hit the *home* key, the cursor will not be at the *actual* start of the overflowing lines, but at the start of the excess characters.

Can I achieve what I mean to achieve without turning word wrap off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double tapping the `home` key will achieve this. Source: [Move cursor to start of line with keyboard shortcut in sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310933/move-cursor-to-start-of-line-with-keyboard-shortcut-in-sublime)